# Backed up site on localhost affecting live site

Tags: localhost, backup

I used BackupBuddy to make a copy of a website I'm working on and then used MAMP (Windows) to recreate the site on my localhost so I could work on it. I must have done something wonky because now the live site loads only the HTML (no CSS) and all of the links are "localhost/..."

I had access to the admin side of the site but never directly interacted with any files on the host server.

I've done a good bit of research on the issue but haven't found anything that matches this scenario.

Any ideas on what happened and how I might fix it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, can you check the contents of your "Hosts" file. If you have trouble finding or opening this file please referrer to [this page to help](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-do-i-modify-my-hosts-file). If there is no reference of your server there warn me and I will post an answer here.

Comment: Hi Bordoni ... The only references to localhost in my hosts file are:

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: Before asking here did you contact the iThemes support? I mean they should have a quick answer for you.

Comment: I didn't - I assumed it was a problem with something else, like maybe a database issue. It didn't seem likely that just installing a cloned version of the site on a localhost could affect the live site. I'll contact iThemes to see if they have any insight ... thanks.

Comment: Where exactly did BackupBuddy create the backup before you accessed it on your local machine? Did you overwrite the site with its own backup?

Comment: I mean, for anyone here to provide you some more help I think you might want to provide what were your steps, just like @barrycarter asked you, because It could be a lot of stuff, that's why I pointed you to the plugin developer support.

Comment: It just creates a zip file that you can access and download on the BackupBuddy admin page on WP dashboard. To install the backup, I just put the zip file and its PHP installer into MAMP > htdocs. The reason I thought it might be a database issue is the fact that links on the live site now are "localhost/..."

Comment: I suspect you may have unzipped the folder on the main server, clobbering your original database and replacing it with the backed up version.

Comment: That would make sense, but I don't have access to the main server. The only places I was working were on the original site's dashboard to get the BackupBuddy zip file and my MAMP localhost. Weird.

Comment: Are database credentials properly updated in your local install and point to your _local_ database server? Is anyone else working with live site? It might have nothing to do with your local copy at all. :)

Comment: Hi Rarst ... I think that's the problem - the database name and credentials in my local wp-config file seem to be the database for the live site. Perhaps I missed a step in the BackupBuddy re-install. I thought that if it's on my localhost I couldn't affect the live site, but clearly I was wrong (I don't have much database experience). Even if that is the problem, I'm still confused how that would affect the CSS/WordPress on the live site. At this point it seems like my only option, since I can't access the live site's dashboard, is to have the hosting company reload an older copy of the site.

Comment: I forgot to add that the database that's in the config-php file is *not* listed as one of the databases in PHPMyAdmin. And I, too, briefly thought that maybe someone else was working on the live site, but since the links point to "localhost/...", I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the database for the local version is still connected to the live version. Check you wp-config file as not all host use local host for databases some use fixed addresses..

Comment: I'm still not sure how it worked, but it's fixed (though some image links are broken but I'm guessing they'll update soon). Here's what I did:

- Started MAMP and went to "http://'live site URL'/wp-login.php" which took me to the WordPress dashboard, though with a localhost URL
- Went to Settings > General and changed the WordPress and Site Address URLs from "http://localhost" to the live site URL

I guess my confusion was in assuming that anything I did on localhost would not affect the live site.

Thanks for the help, everyone.